# Is my apache installation in windows ok?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, apache-http-server, cgi

I am trying to use `Apache2` in `Vista`. I downloaded it and installed it. I did not install it as a service though.
I see in the `Start` a `Start Apache in console` new button that seems to work. I.e. when I put in the `http://localhost/` I see the default apache page indicating that it is running.
Now I have various problems trying to use cgi scripts and I started to look into the installation and I can't understand the following:
The `%APACHE%\modules` directory does not have `dlls`. There are only `.so` files. Isn't this wrong? Shouldn't there be `dlls`?
The `%APACHE%\logs` file has a single log file, namely the `install.log`.
I noticed that when I am in certain directories I see a button named `Compatibility Files`.

[image]

When I press this button (what is this button???) another directory opens in the tree that seems to have the same structure of the apache installation.And in this place I do see the apache's error log. And also the scripts that I placed from `cgi-bin`.

[image]

[image]

I tried to start the apache my self from command prompt but got an error:

> C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\bin>Apache.exe -k start   [Sat
>   May 18 11:30:02 2013] [error] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file
>   specified.  : No installed service named "Apache2".

Is this normal or is my installation messed up?

**UPDATE:**

I noticed the following:
If I update a cgi file under `%APACHE%\cgi-bin` then a corresponding file appears in the directory under `Compatibility Files`.
If I delete the file visible under the `Compatibility Files` view i.e. `AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache 2\cgi-bin\` then the file under the original `Program Files` returns to how it was before I modified it!
I.e. my modifications are lost!!!

Comment: Ah, the [wonders of virtualization](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VistasShowCompatibilityFilesAndTheScrumptiousWonderThatIsFileVirtualization.aspx). :/

Comment: @Karan:Had no idea about this.But how is it possible to not have write permission in the program files?I am the only user and therefore the administrator.

Comment: To simplify, since Vista an admin user is not *the* machine Administrator (to protect people from themselves). See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555910 for more.